# I think I accidently deleted the PATH variable

Tags: bashrc

Whatever I try to run, I get the error:

```
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
```

I had some modification in my .bashrc file but then removed the two additional lines afterwards. However somehow the PATH variable seems to have been destroyed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The PATH should restore on Reboot; anyways, if not the case you can find an Original .bashrc on: /etc/skel/.bashrc Overwrite using it; good luck.

Comment: Here's the base path from a standard user on my system (which has sudo): `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`.  If you put into .bashrc: `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`, then do `source ~/.bashrc`, it may restore the functionality you need.  All this is in the terminal, of course.  **NOTE: I have not tested this!**

Comment: @ThomasW. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll vote on it. Its a life saver. I used this to temporarily fix my PATH and edited ~/.bashrc to fix the offending line.

Comment: @unekwu Just upvote this, or possibly the answer from prime.  I don't need the rep ;)

Answer (score 12):

May be you accidentally did the following.

```
export PATH=<some path>
```

Actually you have replaced the PATH , may be what you should have done is ,

```
export PATH=$PATH:<some path>
```

but this may not be your case. But that same error can be used to recover ,

try below,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

this should work.