# How to add /usr/bin to path after I mistakenly removed it (sudo and nano are no longer in path)

Tags: permissions, sudo, environment-variables, bashrc

Lets get this out of the way, I did something stupid. Yes, stupid. Very stupid. I am well aware of how stupid this is. I am embarrassed and I regret doing it. Please help. I was installing a program, while also watching TV, and somehow managed to remove /usr/bin from path. NOOOOOO.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04. I added the new program bin to path by typing:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

The new path was added, but then I tried to update using sudo and I got this error:

```
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
```

However, the bin still exists:

```
 Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'
```

nano in available, ls is available - its all available - but not in path. So, simply trying:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

and trying to add /usr/bin to path is not an option. Without sudo I dont have permission to open  bashrc. I can cd into /usr/bin, but I cant ls anything, and I have no idea how to access sudo or nano once I'm in there. ./sudo, sudo.sh ./sudo.sh all returns "command not found".

How do I add /usr/bin to path in the event I remove it?

EDIT

I found the solution here: [I think I accidently deleted the PATH variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52611/i-think-i-accidently-deleted-the-path-variable)

I replaced the PATH with the path of the program I added to my path. So, typing this into a terminal gave me access to sudo and nano again:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/sudo su`.

Comment: @N0rbert, I found the answer, please see my edit. I gotta turn the TV off is the real solution.

Comment: FWIW you really shouldn't be using `sudo` to modify files in your own home directory

Comment: @steeldriver, what is the preferred method for permanently adding variables to path?

Comment: @Phil_T it's fine to modify `~/.bashrc` ... just don't do so using `sudo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prefix the commands with the path:

```
/bin/nano ~/.bashrc
```

or (for files that need superuser privilege to edit)

```
/usr/bin/sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: Yeah, that works too. Thanks. My heart dropped for second when sudo stopped working.

Comment: @N0rbert Sorry I didn't notice any comments when I started writing the answer. It could be we were writing at same time? Also since the user is owner of `~/.bashrc` using sudo isn't necessary.